# does FactoryGirl create a record on every create; works from console not in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have the following code in a spec:

```
it 'should save some favorite locations' do
  user=FactoryGirl.create(:user)  # not adding anything
```

and it doesn't seem to write anything to the database. Is FactoryGirl intended to write something with this in a model spec? If I run from the rails console, it does add to the database. Why isn't a test in an rspec isn't running this? Is that how it is intended to work?

thx

Comment: How do you know that it is not writing anything to the DB? Do you mean that it is not *leaving* anything in the DB?

Comment: correct, not leaving anything in DB. Does FG by default clean up before and after each test like DatabaseCleaner (which I'm currently using)?

Comment: it's not FG that is cleaning up, it's rspec using whatever strategy you've told it to use. see @ronalchn's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have configured rspec to use database transactions for each test, or to use database truncation, then any records created are rolled back or destroyed.

To check that it really is adding something, you could try:

```
it 'should save some favorite locations' do
  user=FactoryGirl.create(:user)  # not adding anything
  User.find(user.id).should_not be_nil # ensure it is in database
```

If it passes, then it was added to the database.

If you are using database transactions for your tests, then the database is rolled back after each test. If you need to use a record which is created in multiple tests, you can use:

```
before(:all) do
  @user=FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end
after(:all) do
  @user.destroy # with create in before(:all), it is not in a transaction
                # meaning it is not rolled back - destroy explicitly to clean up.
end
```

Comment: I'm coming in on a project with little docs...  How can I tell if I "have configured rspec to use database transactions for each test, or to use database truncation"?